# First-order logic question: Which one is the translation of “John has exactly one brother ”?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Can anyone help me walk through the following question?

I am struggling to interpret all the 4 options in this question...

[image]

I tried to convert all the options into CNF, but that doesn't make more sense to me when I tried to do the interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Translations:

```
(A) There exist x and y such that x is John's brother 
    and y is John's brother and x = y.
    <=> John has a brother.

(B) If there exists x such that x is John's brother then
    every y is John's brother and x = y.
    <=> If John has a brother then the brother is the
        only person in existence.

(C) If there exists x such that x is John's brother then
    for all y if y is John's brother then y = x.
    <=> If John has a brother then he only has one.

(D) If for all x, x is John's brother, then there exists
    a y such that y is John's brother and x = y.
    <=> If everybody is John's brother then John has
        a brother.

(E) There exists an x such that x is John's brother
    and for all y, if y is John's brother, then x = y.
    <=> John has a brother and he's the only one.
```

The option that corresponds to your statement is (E). It can't be the middle three because those are all conditional (and your statement that John has a brother is not conditional). (A) Does state that John has a brother; however, it does not say that brother is the only one (just that one exists). Technically, (A) says that John has a brother that is the same as the brother himself, which can be said of anybody who has at least one brother.